# custom permission/authorization in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a `json` column named `privacy` in the `users` table.

`users`

```
- id
- privacy JSON
```

The privacy column has a number of settings and the value of the settings in some cases is `boolean` and in other cases is a `string`

```
privacy
{
   "show_profile" : "everyone",
   "show_birth_date" : true
}
```

I want to use the `privacy settings` to

- **allow** ( just return true or false )
- **authorize** ( throw an exception when permission is denied )

I created a class `Bouncer` which is basically a simplified alternative to `Gate` because it would be a mess to define all gates in `AuthServiceProvider`

```
class Bouncer
{
      protected $policies = [
                PrivacyPolicy::class,
        ];
      
      protected $user;
      
      public function allows($action, $user)
      {
              $this->user = $user;
              $policy = $this->policyFor($action);
              
              return $policy->$action();
       }

      public function authorize($action, User $user)
      {
          $this->user = $user;

          $policy = $this->policyFor($action);

          return $policy->$action() ?: abort(403, $policy->messages()[$action]);
    }


       protected function policyFor($action)
       {
            foreach ($this->policies as $policy) {
                if (method_exists($policy, $action)) {
                    return (new $policy($this->user));
                 }
            }
        }
        
}
```

```
class PrivacyPolicy
{
       protected $user;

       public function __construct(User $user)
       {
             $this->user = $user;
       }



       public function show_profile()
       {
            $settingKey = __FUNCTION__;

            return $this->privacy($settingKey);
       }

    protected function privacy($settingKey)
    {
        // this returns the value of a setting 
        // if the settingKey  == 'show_profile'
        // then it returns the value of that setting, which in this particular example 
        // the value of the setting is 'everyone'
        $permission = $this->user->privacy()->$settingKey;

        if (method_exists($this, $permission)) {
            return $this->$permission();
        }

        return $permission;
    }

     public function everyone()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
               'show_profile' => 'This member limits who may view their full profile.',
          ];
    }
}
```

```
class ProfileController
{
       public function show(User $user)
       {
               Bouncer::authorize('show_profile', $user);
       }
}
```

- What do you think of this approach ? is it messy ?
- Is there a package or a better approach ?

Comment: Is there a reason you've opted to use JSON data rather than normalising the privacy settings for the user?

Comment: Hi, I can provide an answer for your last question. I advise that you look into Bouncer and/or Spatie/laravel-permission. Pick the one that suits your needs the best. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction
https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer

Comment: @Daniel The reason is that the number of settings might change and adding a new column for every setting doesn’t seem optimal.

Comment: @jascar_destin thanks, but none of these packages suits my case ( I have already checked them, that’s where I got the name Bouncer from) . Both packages are focused on authorization based on roles/permissions per user.

Comment: The way we typically approach this is by using a roles and permissions table. 

The permissions table would be like your privacy column, and then we have a couple of columns inside the permissions table, the most important one being title (name of the permission such as "show_profile" or "show_birth_date" for example) and then we link it to a role which is finally linked to a user. 

With this approach using the Spatie package mentioned above by @jascar_destin, you can either attach entire roles to users or individual permissions or any combination. Hope that helps.

Comment: @jascar_destin and Daniel I will give an example. If I have user A,B,C,D. If I use any of the packages I would have to give permission to users B,C,D based on the settings of user A. Now imagine that instead of B,C,D you have hundreds of users

Comment: In conclusion, I don’t think that role based authorization is that I need. Because I don’t actually need to give permission and roles to any user. I just need to check the settings of user A, to either allow or deny access to the authenticated user

Comment: Happy to continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232273/custom-permission-authorization-in-laravel)